# Laravel last() with where clause?

Tags: laravel

In my blade template, I've got a last() method.

```
{{ $statuses->last()->body }}
```

Now this works just fine, but can I put a where clause on this? Something like...

```
{{ $statuses->where('something', 0)->last()->body }}
```

Comment: just try. Then ask.

Comment: Well i did, of course.

Comment: @FelixMaxime Please check my answer and let me know if something didn't work out for you.

Comment: $statuses->reverse()->firstWhere('something', 0);
It'd be better to order based some unique columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{ $statuses->where('something', 0)->last()->body }}
```

This does not work because there is nothing in the collection. In other words, the collection returned **after the where** function is actually an empty array and there `last()` gives you `null`

To test this.. you can simply do this

```
dd($statuses->last(), $statuses->where('something', 0)->last());
```

and you would know if I am correct :)

So... To run this, you'll have to do something like

```
{{ $statuses->where('something', 0)->last() ? $statuses->where('something', 0)->last()->body : null }}

//or
if($statuses->where('something', 0)->last()) {
  $statuses->where('something', 0)->last()->body;
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but you should check it for `null` first, because if there is no item with `something = 0` it will return `null`:

```
<?php $item = $statuses->where('something', 0)->last(); >
{{ is_null($item) ? '' : $item->body }}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-last

Answer (score -1):

`last()` method blongs to the Collection class. `Where` returns a query builder.

You need to do:

`...->where(...)->get()->last()`

But this query is very unneficient since you are loading all records to use just one.

Try doing this by sorting your query and using `take(1)` to limit your results.

Comment: Collections have [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-where) method too, so it will not return a query builder.

Comment: Why would last load all records? That sounds super inefficient, since last, by definition, only fetches one record.

Comment: Everything depends on the context. If $statuses contains a collection, my answer is wrong. if it contains a query builder, it's right.